# InfluxDBで設定したretention policyの日時を過ぎてもShardsが消されない

Tags: linux, influxdb

Debian GNU/Linux (VERSION="10 (buster)") 上で InfluxDB (InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.3) を使用しています。

`show retention policy` で確認すると以下の通り72h、デフォルトもtrueなのが確認できます。ただdatabase_aのshardsは72h経過後も消えません。

```
name        duration shardGroupDuration replicaN default
----        -------- ------------------ -------- -------
database_a  72h0m0s  1h0m0s             1        true
```

`sudo system influxdb restart` を実行後、shardsが削除されていることが確認できています。

元々72h経過後に消える時と消えない時があって、そのトリガーはまだ確認できていません。influxdb のサービスをrestartした時に走るクリーンアップprogramを確認したいのですが、どこにそのプログラムが書かれているか分かりますか？また、その他どの部分を確認するべきでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

※この回答は InfluxDB v1 を想定しています。v1 は古いバージョンです。

もし shard group が 72 時間ぴったりでは消えなくてもう少し待つと消えるという挙動のことを指してらっしゃるのであれば、それがドキュメントされた挙動です。以下の具体例が分かりやすいです。

> For example, if your RP has a duration of one day, InfluxDB will drop an hour’s worth of data every hour and will always have 25 shard groups. One for each hour in the day and an extra shard group that is partially expiring, but isn’t removed until the whole shard group is older than 24 hours.

参考

- FAQ: [What is the relationship between shard group durations and retention policies?](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#what-is-the-relationship-between-shard-group-durations-and-retention-policies) -- InfluxDB v1 Documentation
- [Shard group duration management](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/#shard-group-duration-management) -- InfluxDB v1 Documentation

実装としてはこのあたりが参考になりそうです: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/bc80e881fa34aef4145007aa510ffe3e78d3e7ab/services/retention/service.go#L116